# Missing column provided to 'parse_dates'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a CSV file using `pandas.read_csv(...)` using `parse_dates` but I keep getting this:

```
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Data di fine, Data di inizio, Prenotata'`
```

The names of the columns are correct and they are inside a list named `date_cols`:

```
date_cols = ['Data di fine', 'Data di inizio', 'Prenotata']

pd.read_csv('CAMBIAMOVA',  delimiter=';', dtype={"N. di neonati": int,
                                            "Data di inizio": str, "Data di fine": str,
                                             "Prenotata": str}, parse_dates=date_cols)
```

I don't know I'm doing wrong, dates are in this format `"2023-12-28"` in all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter is not correct. It's possible to reproduce the current exception:

CSV file: `CAMBIAMOVA` (comma separated)

```
N. di neonati,Data di fine,Data di inizio,Prenotata
1,2024-01-03,2024-01-01,2024-02-02
```

Wrong delimiter:

```
pd.read_csv('CAMBIAMOVA',  delimiter=';', dtype={"N. di neonati": int,
                                            "Data di inizio": str, "Data di fine": str,
                                             "Prenotata": str}, parse_dates=date_cols)

# Output
...
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Data di fine, Data di inizio, Prenotata'
```

Right delimiter:

```
pd.read_csv('CAMBIAMOVA',  delimiter=',', dtype={"N. di neonati": int,
                                            "Data di inizio": str, "Data di fine": str,
                                             "Prenotata": str}, parse_dates=date_cols)

# Output
   N. di neonati Data di fine Data di inizio  Prenotata
0              1   2024-01-03     2024-01-01 2024-02-02
```

**Edit your file with a simple text editor and check the current delimiter.**

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, WRONG DELIMITER, i feel like an idiot, thank you so much!!